# What markup should I use to describe social media links using schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I have a Place/Local Business that has various fields that map quite nicely to schema.org entries. There is one field I'm not sure how to mark up though. We have links to social media accounts for the business such as their Twitter account, Facebook Page and Pinterest account. How should these be marked up in schema.org?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [proposal for a `socialAccount` property](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/SocialAccountProperty) (and [another one](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/socialAccount2)), and an older discussion about an [`account` property](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2013Jan/0024.html). The relevant issue on Schema.org’s GitHub is [*Social account proposal*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/267) (no comments yet).

But these properties are not there yet (if they’ll come at all).

Of the currently available properties, [`url`](http://schema.org/url), [`sameAs`](http://schema.org/sameAs), and [`contactPoint`](http://schema.org/contactPoint) come to mind:

- `url` could be used if that’s *the* (only) URL of the entity
- `sameAs` could be used if the social media account *represents*/*identifies* exactly the same entity (organization, person, etc.)
- `contactPoint` could be used if the social media account allows *contacting* the entity

Answer (score 1):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.your-company-site.com"> 
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.facebook.com/your-company">FB</a>
  <a itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.twitter.com/YourCompany">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/social-markup/

[image: asdf]

Comment: Link is now broken, and I could not find an equivalent current link in Google's documentation. But there's an [archived version on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190517081815/https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile).