# Defining multiple URLs within a Person

Tags: hyperlink, schema.org, social-media

I'm defining a Schema.org `Person` item on my website using Microdata. Most of it is self-explanatory.

However, each mini profile on a summary page has three URLs - one which links to the Person's full `ProfilePage`, and two more for LinkedIn and Twitter.

Do I define all three as URLs, or do I ignore the social media account URLs, because only the "read more" style link is actually the URL for that person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the link to the person’s profile page on your site, you should ‎definitely use the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url).

For the links to the person’s profiles on other sites, the answer isn’t that clear¹:

- Using the [**`url`**](http://schema.org/url) property wouldn’t be wrong, but [I think it makes sense to use `url` only for your own "canonical" page of the item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046277/1591669).
- Using the [**`contactPoint`**](http://schema.org/contactPoint) property can be appropriate if the profile should be used to contact the person. However, it expects a [`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint) item as value, which might be a bit too expressive for the case of a mere link (but you don’t *have* to follow the expectation, so you could just provide a URL instead of a `ContactPoint` item).
- Using the [**`sameAs`**](http://schema.org/sameAs) property seems to be appropriate if the external profile identifies/represents exactly the same person (and nothing else in addition).

---

¹ There is [no Schema.org property for linking to social media profiles (yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376493/1591669).

Comment: Thanks - the lack of social media links seems like such a weird omission. There's also no property for newsletters or brochures. It seems to be focused on "cool" stuff like movies and music over the utilitarian stuff that will be most useful for businesses.