# How to mark up a Person's websites in Schema.org markup

Tags: schema.org

I'm using [`Person`](https://schema.org/Person) to represent my user's profiles. Users are able to add links to other websites, e.g. their personal website, their Twitter profile, or just the website of an important project of theirs.

The latter is the reason I'd prefer not to use the [`sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) property - plus, I'd like to be able to show the names they give those websites as well.

What property would I be able to use?

Comment: Related: [Defining multiple URLs within a Person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35460009/1591669)

Comment: Thanks @unor, looks like there simply is no property for "generic related links".

Comment: Yes, no such property. But there are properties to provide links that stand in a specific relation to the person (e.g., sites/pages authored by the person, or pages where the person can be contacted, or pages where the person is mentioned, or pages that are about the person etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @unor removed it from the question, I did note that I am marking this up using microdata - which means I can't use `@reverse` like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668182).

What I ended up doing for now is abusing `sameAs` for this, and wrapping it in a [`Role`](https://schema.org/Role) so I could use `roleName` to specify the relation of the website to the profile. So in JSON:

```
{
    "sameAs": [
        {
            "roleName": "My Twitter profile",
            "sameAs": "https://twitter.com/example"
        },
        {
            "roleName": "10001 innovations in scholarly communications",
            "sameAs": "http://innoscholcomm.silk.co/"
        }
    ]
}
```